# Create Azure Blob storage in C with libCURL

Tags: c, azure, curl, libcurl, azure-blob-storage

I would like to create a blob storage on an existing Azure container using C with the libCURL library.

Currently I've successfully used libcurl in C, implementing several RESTApi and connecting my application to the SQL Server, but it seems that POST operations on a blob do not work.

I've tried many different combinations but the server answers with:

**< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>< Error>< Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo< /Code>< Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.**

These are the parameters I've used for the authentication:

**curl -H "Authorization: myuser:MYkey"**

Answer (score 1):

For `Authorization` header, you simply can't use the account key. Essentially the `Authorization` header needs to be specified in the following format:

```
[SharedKey|SharedKeyLite] <AccountName>:<Signature>
```

Please follow the instructions outlined in [`Authentication for the Azure Storage Services`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) for constructing the `<Signature>` part of the authorization header.